# Formatting Chatter FeedItem (With Html?)

Tags: apex, chatter, html, feeditem, formatting

Is there any way to format a Chatter FeedItem.  With html, or with apex methods?

I want to be able to create a feedItem that looks like this

[Sample Chatter Post](http://www.flickr.com/photos/69226159@N07/10694237645/)

Comment: how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, we can't do it in Salesforce Chatter feed. But we can create a custom Chatter site using rails with markdown syntax.

Comment: can you please provide more information.